# React Native Reanimated: How to move View 5 pixels every frame?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I made a quick example using Reanimated / useCode().
— https://snack.expo.io/@yorditwinski/reanimated

I`d like to move the box every frame with 5 pixels.
It's only moving once for 5 pixels. Am I missing something with Clock..?

The concept is pretty new to me and the docs didnt help me out so far.
I come from a Flash background where we had the function "onEnterFrame" which would get fired every frame. So I'm looking for the same in react-native-reanimated.
Thanks in advance :)